Uninstalled Linux and rebooted the computer without deleting GNU GRUB
I have the same situation as stated here: Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader
However, because I never thought of deleting GNU GRUB, I restarted the computer and got stucked here
Computer Screen
None of the solutions above work because it starts from still being in the windows.

This question is similar to: How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You may use the Using a Ubuntu Live DVD and Boot Repair section of the highest rated answer to the link I have posted above. Another alternative is while your computer boots hold down the ESC, F2, F9, or some other key (it varies by computer makes and models) to get to UEFI setup. There you will be able to change the boot option back to Windows.

@user68186 My question was a little different, because what I wanted was to move on from GNU menu and go to windows to do what was expressed on the link i gave, which I couldn't. But I found the solution in your link, because I just needed to press F12 when brand logo appeared to do windows boot. I will leave the question and write the solution anyway

The solution in my case was to press F12 when logo appear and select to do windows boot. Then just do what is mention in the link given in the question.
